# Writing faster select queries on large databases

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables, one with about 1,000 rows and one with 700,000 rows; table1 and table2 respectively. I wrote a simple select query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name1
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.name1 = table2.name2;
```

The query got me exactly what I want but it took 91 seconds! I tried this sub query out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name1
FROM table1
WHERE table1.name1 IN(SELECT DISTINCT name2 FROM table2);
```

That query took a consistent 37 seconds. So there's some performance boost in the way you write select queries. I wrote a third query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1qry
    (SELECT DISTINCT table1.name1 FROM table1);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2qry
    (SELECT DISTINCT table2.name2 FROM table2);

SELECT name2 FROM t2qry JOIN t1qry ON name1 = name2;

DROP TABLE t1qry, t2qry;
```

This last query took 0.4 seconds to run and produced identical results to the other two.

I knew that each 'select distinct' query took less than a second to run so I was trying to craft one that would find common distinct values between the table. My question is why does what I wrote work?  How do I write a faster select query like this without creating temporary tables?

I've been using MySQL and MariaDB but I'll take any SQL related help here. I'm new to SQL and have been trying to learn as much as I can, so I'll take any pointers or info about this.

Comment: An index would be useful on those tables

Comment: Are you including the time spent creating the temporary tables?

Comment: You should include the table definition. I think you should also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33206756/4594973).

Comment: @Gordon That does include time spent creating and dropping the temporary tables, which only have results of 155 and 180 rows each.

Comment: @ray The fields name1 and name2 are VARCHAR(45). I'm not well versed in sql theory and how to make queries faster by building better tables.

Comment: @UnicornMaster: Have you tried using the `explain` keyword to see what the query execution plan looks like? Please prefix your SQL queries with it and, in addition to posting the table definition, please post the QEP results. It's difficult to know what to say without knowing what the QEP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If your latter version (including creating the temporary tables) goes so fast, then you probably have indexes on `nameX` in both tables.

I would suggests using `exists`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name1
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.name1 = table2.name2);
```

For these queries, you do want indexes on `table1(name1)` and `table2(name2)`.

And, if `table1` has no duplicates, then leave out the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I put a WHERE between table2 and table1.name1, and your query was certainly faster than my first two, ~15 seconds. I don't really know why though.What does it mean to have an index on a column in a table?

Comment: @UnicornMaster . . . An index is a feature in a database that allows certain queries to run faster.

Comment: An index associates a reference value, like a name, with a record address. Because they're relatively small, and only unique values are stored in them, indexes can be stored in memory, so reading is fast. If you intend to join on a column, use an index. Otherwise, the entire database table has tip be scanned, which is expensive.