# Making thousands of SELECT queries faster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pymysql

### Situation

- Working with Python 3.7.2
- I have read previlege of a MariaDB table with 5M rows on a server.
- I have a local text file with 7K integers, one per line.
- The integers represent IDXs of the table.
- The IDX column of the table is the primary key. (so I suppose it is automatically indexed?)

### Problem

I need to select all the rows whose IDX is in the text file.

### My effort

#### Version 1

Make 7K queries, one for each line in the text file. This makes approximately 130 queries per second, costing about 1 minute to complete.

```py
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(....)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = (
        "SELECT *"
        " FROM TABLE1"
        " WHERE IDX = %(idx)s;"
    )

    all_selected = {}
    with open("idx_list.txt", "r") as f:
        for idx in f:
            idx = idx.strip()
            if idx:
                idx = int(idx)
                parameters = {"idx": idx}
                cursor.execute(query, parameters)
                result = cursor.fetchall()[0]
                all_selected[idx] = result
```

#### Version 2

Select the whole table, iterate over the cursor and cherry-pick rows. The for-loop over `.fetchall_unbuffered()` covers 30-40K rows per second, and the whole script costs about 3 minutes to complete.

```py
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(....)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"

    set_of_idx = set()
    with open("idx_list.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                line = int(line.strip())
                set_of_idx.add(line)


    all_selected = {}
    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor.fetchall_unbuffered():
        if row[0] in set_of_idx:
            all_selected[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

### Expected behavior

I need to select faster, because the number of IDXs in the text file will grow as big as 10K-100K in the future.

I consulted other answers including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758979/writing-faster-select-queries-on-large-databases), but I can't make use of it since I only have read previlege, thus impossible to create another table to join with.

So how can I make the selection faster?

Comment: Why not load the text file into a table?

Comment: @Strawberry Is it possible with a read-only access to the database?

Comment: Can you be granted priv to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`?

Comment: @danblack I'll have to talk to the DB manager, and if so, I understand I'd be able to `JOIN` the two tables, probably solving the problem. If not, then do I have not much chance?

Comment: Show the DB manager your alternate code. That should be sufficient encouragement to grant you the required `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` access. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary table implementation would look like:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(....,local_infile=True)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE R (IDX INT PRIMARY KEY)")
    cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'idx_list.txt' INTO R")
    cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE1.* FROM TABLE1 JOIN R USING ( IDX )")
    ..
    cursor.execute("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE R")
```

Comment: I was working on this (looking up the documentation to load data) when stack overflow notified me of your answer... and thanks! I would've had to spend more than half an hour to cover all necessary documentation.

Comment: @Taegyung keep in mind that the memory table can be converted into running on disk instead off running in memory, but this should the DBA's know over there..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint (or more than a *hint*) from @danblack, I was able to achieve the desired result with the following query.

```py
query = (
    "SELECT *"
    " FROM TABLE1"
    " INNER JOIN R"
    " ON R.IDX = TABLE1.IDX;"
)
cursor.execute(query)
```

danblack's `SELECT` statement didn't work for me, raising an error:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDX' at line 1")

This is probably because of MariaDB's join syntax, so I consulted the [MariaDB documentation on joining tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/joining-tables-with-join-clauses/).

And now it selects 7K rows in 0.9 seconds.

Leaving here as an answer just for the sake of completeness, and for future readers.

Comment: opp. Corrected in my answer `...USING ( IDX )`